# Convert NE555 square wave output to triangular wave using op-amp(s)

Tags: timer, 555

I want to generate a square wave with 45% duty cycle and 465Hz on an NE555 timer and then convert that wave into a triangular wave using op amps.
I have a circuit schematic but the output generates flat signals on both ends.
I don't understand what the issue is.

Please help as it is for a group project of important nature.
Thank You.[image]

Comment: Would something like [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/433890/38098) help?

Comment: what is the purpose of R6?

Comment: @jonk OP was asking for triangular in this case, not sawtooth (which is slightly harder to implement).

Comment: @Kalle One never knows for sure. Often a sawtooth can be useful used where a triangle also works. So I was just asking, is all.

Comment: You have the simulation in front of you. Start probing different signals, starting from the inputs, until you find a signal that doesn't look like it should.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).